# Using 'width' property only with big texts

Tags: css

I want to put a `width:200` only when my text is very big but if not, it should not have the width property

Is that possible?

```css
.cut-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cut-text">
    its should yes its should yes its should yes
  </div>
  <div class="cut-text">
    its should no
  </div>
  <div class="cut-text">
    its should no
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width`

```css
.cut-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  max-width: 200px;
  border:1px solid;
  height: 1.2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="cut-text">
    its should yes its should yes its should yes
  </div>
  <div class="cut-text">
    its should no
  </div>
  <div class="cut-text">
    its should no
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with .cut-text:first-of-type {
...
}

It will only give style to the first class div, or you can add an additional class to the first div, and set the special width.